# connect to sql in c++?

Tags: c++, sql, oracle, oracle10g

I want to connect to sql using c++.

I have g++ (sparc-sun-solaris2.10-g++) installed on my UNIX machine and the sql version is SQL*Plus: Release 10.2.0.4.0.

I want to write a c++ code by which I want to connect to sql.

Using shell script I can easily connect to the DB but using c++ I don't know how to do it.

Thanks .

I have this piece of code but this is failing while I *compile* :

error :

### Creating library libr9.so  20110308_083331

ld: fatal: file /tlmsr1/tlm/rt/kimi/proj/c9rprOG/crp/templates.a: open failed: No such file or directory
ld: fatal: file /tlmsr1/tlm/rt/kimi/proj/c9rprOG/crp/templates.a: open failed: No such file or directory
ld: fatal: File processing errors. No output written to /tlmsr1/tlm/rt/kimi/proj/c9rprOG/lib/libcrpr9.so
gmake: *** [libr9.so] Error 1

code :

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <occi.h>
#include <iostream>
using namespace oracle::occi;
using namespace std;



class testOcci
{
  private:

  Environment *env;
  Connection *conn;

  public:

 testOcci (string user, string passwd, string db)
  {
    env = Environment::createEnvironment (Environment::DEFAULT);
    conn = env->createConnection (user, passwd, db);
  }

  /**
   * Destructor for the occi test case.
   */
  ~testOcci ()
  {
    env->terminateConnection (conn);
    Environment::terminateEnvironment (env);
  }  // end of ~testOcci ()

};

int main(void)
{
string user="sbsdb6";
string passwd="sbsdb6";
string db="ABPDV";

testOcci *demo = new testOcci (user, passwd, db);
cout << "Creation Successful" << endl;
delete (demo);
cout << "Deletion Successful" << endl;

return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Since it seems as though you mean *Oracle* when you say *sql* I think you want to try `OCCI` . In that case [this link](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/features/oci/index-090820.html) might help.

But... using OCCI is *quite different* from connecting to Oracle with a shell script via `SQL*Plus`.

Comment: I can view the same db using sql and oracle both.

Comment: wr@sn25666!M3G:sbswrk6/pbin/app> g++  sqlconnect.cpp -o sqlconnect.o
sqlconnect.cpp:25:18: occi.h: No such file or directory
sqlconnect.cpp:27: error: `oracle' has not been declared
sqlconnect.cpp:27: error: expected namespace-name before ';' token
sqlconnect.cpp:27: error: `<type error>' is not a namespace
sqlconnect.cpp:36: error: ISO C++ forbids declaration of `Environment' with no type
sqlconnect.cpp:36: error: expected `;' before '*' token

Answer (score 2):

You might also take a look at those two libs.
[OTL](http://otl.sourceforge.net/) and [SOCI](http://soci.sourceforge.net/).
I used both in some projects and they worked fine for me.

Comment: wr@sn25666!M3G:sbswrk6/pbin/app> g++  sqlconnect.cpp -o sqlconnect.o
sqlconnect.cpp:25:18: occi.h: No such file or directory
sqlconnect.cpp:27: error: `oracle' has not been declared
sqlconnect.cpp:27: error: expected namespace-name before ';' token
sqlconnect.cpp:27: error: `<type error>' is not a namespace
sqlconnect.cpp:36: error: ISO C++ forbids declaration of `Environment' with no type
sqlconnect.cpp:36: error: expected `;' before '*' token

Comment: Sorry I cannot help you much with this error. I never used OCCI directly.

Comment: hi , The library you mentioned you used in VC++, I am using gnu compiler with eclipse ide. Do you have any idea how to do it with gnu c++.

Comment: Yes I used them on Windows. But I have seen the usage of OTL in Tora[http://torasql.com/]. And you are able to find examples for both libs on their homepages. They should compile under linux just like under windows.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use ODBC libraries to connect and retrieve data from a RDBMS. [This](http://www.easysoft.com/developer/languages/c/odbc_tutorial.html) seems to be a good starting point.

Comment: using script I do like like :data=`sqlplus -s "$@" <<EOF
set serveroutput on
set feedback off
set head off
spool $TempSynonymlog append;
DECLARE
        count1 number(4);
        CURSOR cursor_table IS
    SELECT table_name FROM dst_tables_list@SBOPR where table_name like '%PM1%' or table_name like '%GN1%' or table_name like '%OLC%';
        name varchar2(100) ;
        name1 varchar2(100) ;
        sqlstatement varchar2(100);
 headerFlag number(1) :=0;

Comment: ODBC is available on Unix but it will call the Oracle libraries which I would call directly as per @René Nyffenegger

Comment: @doron - It's certainly available in Linux, we use ODBC connections on our Ubuntu 10 Server to connect to MS SQL Server.

Comment: @doron :ODBC is very much available on unix, Vendors like Data Direct specialize on providing ODBC libraries across all platforms. Please verify your questions before downvoting.

Answer (score 0):

Try the class named CDatabase.
Create a connection to the databse.
And  a function named ExecuteSQL() using which u can execute queries.
For fetching the results u have CResultSet class.
If you find difficulty post here.. i wil send u the sample.

thanks
Arun P.

Comment: HI Arun , I am not using vc++ , simple gcc complier. I can add other libraries (required for oracle connection) . If you have sample please send me . Thanks and appreciate ur help